# Assign keys to delimited values in all list items

Tags: r

I have the following data structure:

```
keys <- c("key1", "key2", "key3")
values <- c("val1_val2_val3", "wert1_wert2_wert3", "n1_n2_n3", "out1_out2_out3")
```

I want to combine these lists so that every key gets mapped to the corresponding chunk for each list element. For example, the response for requesting the first `key1` should yield to:

```
response$key1
> "val1" "wert1" "n1" "out1"
```

Do you have clue how to solve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can split `values` on `'_'`, combine them as matrix and split column-wise.

```
response <- setNames(asplit(do.call(rbind, strsplit(values, "_")), 2), keys)
#Similarly
#response <- setNames(asplit(do.call(cbind, strsplit(values, "_")), 1), keys)
response

#$key1
#[1] "val1"  "wert1" "n1"    "out1" 

#$key2
#[1] "val2"  "wert2" "n2"    "out2" 

#$key3
#[1] "val3"  "wert3" "n3"    "out3"
```

---

This is short and almost gives similar output

```
purrr::transpose(strsplit(values, "_"), .names = keys)
```

Comment: asplit.... R has just a sick amount of function that I have not yet discovered. Thanks Ronak, it works!